# Is it possible to receive a list of execution Arns per state machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

My compandy is using AWS Stepfunctions. Now I need a list of all the executions Arns for a single state machine.

What I want, is the `input` parameter from an execution.
For this I am currently looking at this workflow:

1. Get the list of executions from a state machine `aws stepfunctions list-executions --state-machine-arn $ARN`
2. Iterate through the list, read out the execution arns
3. Get the execution Info per execution with `aws stepfunctions describe-execution --execution-arn $ARN`

Is there a simple command chain you could use, or do I need to continue using my bashscript, parsing JSON outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell commands to do this are:

```
aws stepfunctions list-executions \
  --state-machine-arn <YOUR STEP FN ARN> \
  --query "executions[*].{executionArn:executionArn}" \
  --output text | \
xargs -I {} aws stepfunctions describe-execution \
  --execution-arn {} \
  --query "executionArn"
```

The `--query` argument filters the `list-executions` output to the field that you are interested in. This field is then passed to `describe-execution` and another `--query` argument obtains the `executionArn` field.

---

To write each output to a separate file:

```
aws stepfunctions list-executions \
  --state-machine-arn <YOUR STEP FN ARN> \
  --query "executions[*].{executionArn:executionArn}" \
  --output text | \
xargs -I {} \
  sh -c \
  'aws stepfunctions describe-execution --execution-arn $1 \
   --query executionArn >> "output-$(echo $1 | cut -d: -f8)"' -- {}
```

The second aws cli command writes to a file name with the prefix `output-` followed by the name of the execution (the 8th field of the ARN).

Comment: Thanks, that works fine! And the explaination is very appreciated!

Comment: How would you write each output to a seperate file?

Comment: Is there a way to save the executions as a list, to iterate over at a later time? If i execute the aws list-executions like so `execution_arns="$(aws stepfunctions list-executions ...)"`, I can't iterate the list, it returns always all execution arns

Comment: Redirect the output of the aws command to a file to save it. Then use xargs with the `-a` parameter. There should be multiple answers to how to do this on SO and https://unix.stackexchange.com/.